# ¿solucion para este error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at Object.success?

Tags: javascript, html

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnBuscar").click(function () {
        var busqueda = $("#buscar").val();
        console.log(busqueda);
        $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + busqueda,

            function (data, status) {
                console.log(status);
                console.log(data);
                var largo = data.items;

                for (var i = 0; i < largo.length; i++) {

                    text = "";
                    for (var j = 0; j < largo.length; j++) {
                        text = text + '<div class=resultado' + j + '>' + '<h class="sep-imp-2>' +
                               'titulo del libro' + '</h2>' + '<br>' + '<h3>' +  '< Autor>' +'</h3>' + '<br>' +
                               '<i>' + '<Isbn>' + '</i>' + '<p>' + '</p>' + '<img src="">' + '</div>' + '</div>'
                                ;

                     }
                     document.getElementById("divs").innerHTML =text;
                     for (var k = 0; k < largo.length; k++) {
                         var titulo = data.items[k].volumeInfo.title;
                         var autor = data.items[k].volumeInfo.authors[0];
                         var industria = data.items[k].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].idetifier;
                         var descripcion = data.items[k].volumeInfo.description;
                         var imagen = data.items[k].volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail;

                         $('#resultado .impreso' + k + ' h2').html(titulo);
                         $('#resultado .impreso' + k + ' h3').html(autor);
                         $('#resultado .impreso' + k + ' i').html("ISBN " + industria);
                         $('#resultado .impreso' + k + ' p').html(descripcion);
                         $('#resultado .impreso' + k + ' img').attr("src", imagen);
                     }    
                 }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

estas usando Jquery, asi que puedes cambiar

```
document.getElementById("divs").innerHTML =text;
```

por

```
$("#divs").html() = text;
```

Sin embargo el error es porque no tienes un elemento con el id "divs" , así que puedes agregarlo en el HTML de esta forma

```
<div id="divs"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

El error ocurre en ésta línea:

```
document.getElementById("divs").innerHTML =text;
```

Te indica que no puede acceder a la propiedad innerHtml de algo que es nulo y es porque la función getElementByID no encontró en el html un elemento con el id "divs".